R: Pass character vector of column names to function which can optionally take multiple arguments
My specific issue involves the function tabyl from the janitor package, but it may be also be relevant to other cases.
I am trying to pass a character vector with column names as parameters to a custom function which creates a summary table. I should be able to pass either 1, 2 or 3 names, as the tabyl function can accept either of those. However, tabyl only recognises my vector as a single parameter, using the first element and ignoring the others.
The reason I prefer to feed a vector to my custom function instead of individual names is because I am doing other manipulations on the vector.
I have tried using do.call to extract the vector elements as in other solutions, but struggle to combine it alongside the tidyselect command all_of, which I presumably need to interpret the character elements as column names.
My code is currently:
library("tidyverse")
library("janitor")

table_func <- function(data=NULL,
                       vars=NULL) {
  
  data %>% tabyl(all_of(vars))

  # Other code involving "all_of(vars)"

}

dat <- tibble(x=c(1:4),y=c(5:8))

vc <- c("x","y")

table_func(dat,vc)

Current output:
 x n percent
 1 1    0.25
 2 1    0.25
 3 1    0.25
 4 1    0.25

Desired output:
 x 5 6 7 8
 1 1 0 0 0
 2 0 1 0 0
 3 0 0 1 0
 4 0 0 0 1


Do you have to use tabyl?  An alternative might be table(dat[vc]) or if it is important that it be a data frame use as.data.frame.matrix on that.

Thanks for the suggestion, a base approach is always good, but I am indeed quite keen on tabyl. I've looked at different summary stats functions for one that appeals to me, and I prefer tabyl for now - in part because I also like other janitor functions like adorn_totals(), which it integrates with seamlessly.

table(dat[vc]) |> addmargins()

This would work if tabyl() was dplyr::select(), but evidently the janitor package, or this function, doesn't support the same tidy select syntax.
base R approach
When I get into this kind of tidy evaluation pit of doom, I try to claw my way out with base R.
You want to call: tabyl(data, ...), where the ... is each element in vars. You can do this with do.call() which

constructs and executes a function call from a name or a function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.

The other issue is that you are supplying a character vector, but we need names (i.e. tabyl(data, x, y) rather than tabyl(data, "x", "y"). So we use as.name() on each element of vars.
table_func <- function(data, vars) {
    tabyl |>
        do.call(c(list(data), lapply(vars, as.name)))
}

table_func(dat, vc)
#  x 5 6 7 8
#  1 1 0 0 0
#  2 0 1 0 0
#  3 0 0 1 0
#  4 0 0 0 1

tidyverse approach
If you want to stick with the tidyverse you can use !!!, the splice operator. Note that:

Most tidyverse functions support !!! out of the box. With base functions you need to use inject() to enable !!!.

library(rlang)
table_func <- function(data, vars) {
    data |>
        tabyl(!!!parse_exprs(vars)) |>
        inject()
}

table_func(dat, vc)
#  x 5 6 7 8
#  1 1 0 0 0
#  2 0 1 0 0
#  3 0 0 1 0
#  4 0 0 0 1

A note on pipes
As you noted in your comment, if you want to use the magrittr pipe, the above will not work:
table_func <- function(data, vars) {
    data %>%
        tabyl(!!!parse_exprs(vars)) %>%
        inject()
}
table_func(dat, vc)
# Error in `rlang::enquo()`:
# ! Can't use `!!!` at top level.
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Let's look at the abstract syntax tree (AST) of the function without pipes:
table_func_pipeless <- function(data, vars) {
    inject(tabyl(data, !!!parse_exprs(vars)))
}

This is exactly the same as the AST produced with the native pipe:
█─inject 
└─█─tabyl 
  ├─data 
  ├─x 
  └─y 

However, if we pass the magritrr version to lobstr::ast(), we get:
█─`%>%` 
├─█─`%>%` 
│ ├─data 
│ └─█─tabyl 
│   ├─x 
│   └─y 
└─█─inject 

This is because %>% is a function call, whereas the native pipe is parsed as the table_func_pipeless() expression.
I would just use the base R pipe. As Hadley Wickham states:

Luckily there’s no need to commit entirely to one pipe or the other — you can use the base pipe for the majority of cases where it’s sufficient and use the magrittr pipe when you really need its special features.

If you really want to use the magritr pipe, you can achieve the desired output by wrapping the entire expression in inject().
table_func_magrittr <- function(data, vars) {
    inject(data %>% tabyl(!!!parse_exprs(vars)))
}

table_func_magrittr(dat, vc)
#  x 5 6 7 8
#  1 1 0 0 0
#  2 0 1 0 0
#  3 0 0 1 0
#  4 0 0 0 1

For more see: What are the differences between R's native pipe `|>` and the magrittr pipe `%>%`?

Thank you for providing both alternatives. I'll admit to preferring tidyverse solutions as it somehow seems more intuitive to me and others I work with, but it is good to understand how a base approach works.  On your latter solution, I tried replacing |> with %>% for consistency and as I thought they were equivalent, but it doesn't work. Any idea why?

@Modern_ibex I know you've already accepted the answer, but I've edited to add a little more about this difference and how you can use the magrittr pipe if you want to.

@SamR, Maybe you could add an issue to janitor about this.  Specifying the columns seems complex unless you hard code the column names.

@G.Grothendieck I agree it seems complicated. It's not really a package I use a lot though so I'm not sure I'm in a good position to make suggestions about changes.

@SamR Thank you again, also for adding the section on the pipes, I found that very useful and hopefully others would too. @G.Grothendieck, I agree it may be fruitful to pursue the issue - I assumed my vector would work as in tidyselect since the tabyl vignette states "tabyl() is tidyverse-aligned and is primarily built upon the dplyr and tidyr packages." I don't know whether the team accepts suggestions though, since it is probably not strictly an "issue".

@Modern_ibex a feature request is a legitimate GitHub issue. In fact they've had similar requests in the past which they've implemented - so I say go for it. Plus sometimes I find you get a quick win with these kinds of requests when package maintainers tell you no new features are necessary because in fact there's a much simpler way of doing things.
